# iCarousel with bigger images are Overlapping

Tags: objective-c

How can I solve the issue of overlapping by bigger images in iPad while implementing iCarousel animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this protocol to your class `<iCarouselDeprecated>`
Then implement

```
- (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    return 200.0;
}
```

Comment: That is a hacky solution because in most cases you have different image widths.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the below property.

```
iCarouselTranformOptionRadius
```

**The radius of the Rotary, Cylinder and Wheel transforms in pixels/points. This is usually calculated so that the number of items (count) exactly fits into the specified arc. You can manipulate this value to increase or reduce the item spacing (and the radius of the circle).**

For more reference just read the read-me file [here](https://github.com/AalokParikh/iCarousel)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a wild guess, have you tried setting `-setClipsToBounds:` to `YES` on the UIImageViews in the carousel?